# New record isn't loading until application restarted using C# with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm using a MySQL database with a C# application. I have the application set to use a form to add a new record and display existing records. Once a record is inserted, the form should re-grab records from the database, and display the last record in the table in the form (ie. the newly created record).

As it stands, it's showing the first record as the first and last record when clicking on previous/next or first/last to browse through the records in the table. It seems to be looping the the first one in the data adapter for some reason. I'm new to using MySQL with C#. Is there a way that this can be reset or updated without having to restart the application?

To populate the form, it's calling the same method as on form load, connecting to the database, getting the row count, filling the data adapter, populating the text boxes, and then closing the connection to the database. Not sure why it can't grab everything the second, etc, time around.

When the user clicks add to add the new record:

```
//Recounts rows in table in the table
numberOfRows = GetRowCount("tblTable");

//Resets displayedRow counter and updates form data to show new record
displayedRow = numberOfRows - 1;
UpdateFormData(displayedRow);
```

The number of records is updating on the form properly, so I know that's working alright.

Then in the UpdateFormData method:

```
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `tblTable`;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Fill DataAdapter
using (tblTableDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
   tblTableDataAdapter.Fill(tblTableDataTable);
}

tblTableDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, connection);
       tblTableDataAdapter.Fill(tblTableDataSet);

//Displays row data in textbox
textBox1.Text = tblTableSet.Tables[0].Rows[displayedRow]["FirstName"].ToString();
       textBox2.Text = tblTablefDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[displayedRow]["LastName"].ToString();
       textBox3.Text = tblTableDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[displayedRow]["StaffAddress"].ToString();
       textBox4.Text = tblStaffDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[displayedRow]["PostalCode"].ToString();
       textBox5.Text = tblTableDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber]["City"].ToString();
       textBox6.Text = tblTableDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber]["Phone"].ToString();
       textBox7.Text = tblTableDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[rowNumber]["Email"].ToString();
```

Comment: After updating the values you have to refill the table

Comment: I have that on line 8 of the update method, and apparently on line 12. Would that be better on another line?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the problem. The dataset needed to be reset before refilling the data adapter. Changed the update method to include:

```
tblTableDataSet.Reset();
tblTableDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, connection);
tblTableDataAdapter.Fill(tblTableDataSet);
```

And it's showing the new record now.